# Using variable for Image in SwiftUI makes images invisible in view

Tags: swift, image, swiftui, constructor

I have a data set where one parameter is a String, referring to an image which is passed into an Image constructor, looking something like this.

```
var GameData = [GameDataModel(image: "game.jpg", title: "Legend of Zelda")
```

My object class looks like this.

```
struct GameView: View {
    @State var gameData: [GameDataModel]
    
    var body: some View {
        ForEach(gameData) { game in
            ZStack {
                Image(game.image) // <------------------ passing in parameter
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 180, height: 250)
                    .cornerRadius(5)
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

Which is called in the main view as so:

```
ScrollView {
    LazyVGrid(columns: columns, spacing: 15) {
        GameView(gameData: GameData)
    }
}
```

My goal is to get these images to show up in a grid, which it does, but the images are invisible.

From what I saw online, I need to make the image variable @Published or something like that, but I'm not sure how I would be able to do that when I'm getting it from this data set.  I tried just making the original GameData variable @Published but that gave me errors so I'm not quite sure what to do.

Comment: if your images are in your `Assets.xcassets` directory,
 then you can omit the `.jpg` extention. Try using
 `[GameDataModel(image: "game", title: "Legend of Zelda"),...]

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the view, it's how you load images that is failing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your images are in your `Assets.xcassets` directory,
then remove the `.jpg` extention when referring to them.

Note, use the standard convention of lower case for variables, and uppercase for types.

Although your code would work, you could consider some re-structure of your code, to present a grid of images, like this:

```
struct GameDataModel: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var image: String
    var title: String
}

struct ContentView: View {
    // no extention to file names
    let gameData = [
        GameDataModel(image: "game", title: "Legend of Zelda"),
        GameDataModel(image: "game", title: "Legend of Zelda"),
        GameDataModel(image: "game", title: "Legend of Zelda"),
        GameDataModel(image: "game", title: "Legend of Zelda"),
        GameDataModel(image: "game", title: "Legend of Zelda"),
        GameDataModel(image: "game", title: "Legend of Zelda"),
        GameDataModel(image: "game", title: "Legend of Zelda")
    ]
    
    let columns = [
        GridItem(.flexible(), spacing: 1), GridItem(.flexible(), spacing: 1), GridItem(.flexible(), spacing: 1)
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            LazyVGrid(columns: columns, spacing: 15) {
                ForEach(gameData) { game in
                    GameView(game: game)  // <-- here
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct GameView: View {
    @State var game: GameDataModel  // <-- here
    
    var body: some View {
        Image(game.image)  // <-- here
            .resizable()
            .frame(width: 180, height: 250)
            .cornerRadius(5)
    }
}
```